# Javascript not found in Laravel 8 project

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to include some Javascripts in to my Laravel project, by following the already included ones. I have a blade which is starting like that.

```
@extends('layouts.boss-layout')

@section('css_before')
    <!-- Page JS Plugins CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('js/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('js/plugins/datatables/buttons-bs4/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css') }}">
@endsection

@section('js_after')
    <!-- Page JS Plugins -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/plugins/datatables/buttons/dataTables.buttons.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/plugins/datatables/buttons/buttons.print.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/plugins/datatables/buttons/buttons.html5.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/plugins/datatables/buttons/buttons.flash.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/plugins/datatables/buttons/buttons.colVis.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/plugins/datatables/buttons/dataTables.responsive.min.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- Page JS Code -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/pages/boss_main_dashboard.js') }}"></script>
@endsection

@section('content')
```

In the source above, the last two assets are added by me. dataTables.responsive.min.js and boss_main_dashboard.js. In boss_main_dashboard.js there is the following content...

```
class pageTablesDatatables {
    /*
     * Init DataTables functionality
     *
     */
    alert('asdasd');
    static initDataTables() {
        // Override a few default classes
        jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.classes, {
            sWrapper: "dataTables_wrapper dt-bootstrap4",
            sFilterInput:  "form-control form-control-sm",
            sLengthSelect: "form-control form-control-sm",
            responsive: true
        });

        // Override a few defaults
        jQuery.extend(true, jQuery.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
            language: {
                lengthMenu: "_MENU_",
                search: "_INPUT_",
                searchPlaceholder: "Search..",
                info: "Page <strong>_PAGE_</strong> of <strong>_PAGES_</strong>",
                paginate: {
                    first: '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>',
                    previous: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
                    next: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
                    last: '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>'
                }
            }
        });
        
        // Init full DataTable
        jQuery('.js-dataTable-full').dataTable({
            pageLength: 5,
            lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 15, 20], [5, 10, 15, 20]],
            autoWidth: true
        });

        // Init DataTable with Buttons
        jQuery('.js-dataTable-buttons').dataTable({
            pageLength: 5,
            lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 15, 20], [5, 10, 15, 20]],
            autoWidth: false,
            buttons: [
                { extend: 'copy', className: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary' },
                { extend: 'csv', className: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary' },
                { extend: 'print', className: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary' }
            ],
            dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'<'text-center bg-body-light py-2 mb-2'B>>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-6'f>><'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>"
        });
    }

    /*
     * Init functionality
     *
     */
    static init() {
        this.initDataTables();
    }
}

// Initialize when page loads
jQuery(() => { pageTablesDatatables.init(); });
```

Now, in "View Source" of the page I can clearly see that the script tags are added but they certainly don't "run" whatsoever. When I click on the linked Javascript URLs from the "View Source" screen, I get a 404 not found error, like below.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your js files are in the /resources/js folder instead of the /public/js?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack run:

```
npm run dev //for dev environment
```

You must assure that you have following files in `/resources/js` directory.

If you are not using webpack check if files exist in directory `/public/js`.